# How to show a specific div when a link is clicked and hide others?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show only one div when the user clicks the links on the icon bar and hide others. When the user clicks home link of the icon bar only 'hoediv'is visible and others hidden.
My work is below please help!!

```
<!doctype HTML>

<head>

<div class="main-header-div">
<a id="home" href="" > Home</a>
<a id="about" href=""> About us</a>
</div>
</head>

<body>
<script>
$(function(){
$("#home").click(function(){
    $("#homediv").show();
$("#aboutus").hide();
return false;
});

});
</script>
<div id="homediv" style="color:white; background-color:red;height:89px;         
width:100%;font-size:150%; display:none;">This is my site.  
</div>
<div id="aboutus" style="display:none;">
this is about us page
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have div inside your head tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you need to fix?**

- Firstly, `<head></head>` only includes metadata, the rest should be in the `<body></body>`.
- If you're not going to make use `<a>` anchor tags for hyperlinking, then pass the value `href="JavaScript:Void(0);"` *(The void operator evaluates the given expression and then returns undefined)*  or better yet, don't use anchor tags better yet span or button.
- You didn't import `jquery.js` in your html file.
- You can make this *a lot more effecient*, but I'd suggest you learn some basic html from the widely available sources and then CSS, Jquery,etc.

**Sources to refer:**

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

```js
$(function() {
  $("#home").click(function() {
    $("#homediv").show();
    $("#aboutus").hide();
  });
  $("#about").click(function() {
    $("#homediv").hide();
    $("#aboutus").show();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-header-div">
  <a id="home" href="JavaScript:Void(0);"> Home</a>
  <a id="about" href="JavaScript:Void(0);"> About us</a>
</div>

<div id="homediv" style="color:white; background-color:red;height:89px;         
width:100%;font-size:150%; display:none;">This is my site.
</div>
<div id="aboutus" style="display:none;">
  this is about us page
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simplify it, you can use classes and data attributes to toggle wanted content:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-header-div">
  <a class="header-link" id="home" data-toggle="homediv" href="#" > Home</a>
  <a class="header-link" id="about" data-toggle="aboutus" href="#"> About us</a>
</div>

<div class="content" id="homediv" style="color:white; background-color:red;height:89px;         
width:100%;font-size:150%; display:none;">
  This is my site.  
</div>
<div class="content" id="aboutus" style="display:none;">
  this is about us page
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".header-link").click(function(){
      $(".content").hide();
      $("#" + $(this).attr("data-toggle")).show();
  });
  
});
</script>
```